# Rails 3 app running on Nginx and Unicorn in production not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, unicorn, production

I've got a bit of a strange issue with my personal rails app.

For over a year now I've been running it on a VPS using  Nginx, Unicorn and RVM, I'm not the best with production set ups but wanted to start getting better at it so I followed Ryan Bates' Railscast on the subject [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps) It seemed to be working really well for a long time but recently I've noticed that in order to get the homepage to refresh when new articles are added I am having to kill the Unicorn Processes and then restart unicorn.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? If so how would I go about rectifying it?

Answer (score 0):

**New Answer:**

Based on your comments, this is most likely not a Unicorn / Nginx issue, but just an issue with Rails switching between development & production. Try running your site locally, but on production mode.

Most likely you've got caches that need to be blown away every time someone posts a new article. If you're getting lots of traffic, you'll want to cache, but forgetting to reset the cache can cause the problem you're seeing.

**Old Answer:**

Do you use capistrano? There's a set of recipes for using unicorn with capistrano. They have a task for reloading unicorn:

https://github.com/sosedoff/capistrano-unicorn/blob/master/lib/capistrano-unicorn/capistrano_integration.rb#L103

This is mentioned in the docs:

http://unicorn.bogomips.org/SIGNALS.html

> HUP - reloads config file and gracefully restart all workers. If the “preload_app” directive is false (the default), then workers will also pick up any application code changes when restarted. If “preload_app” is true, then application code changes will have no effect; USR2 + QUIT (see below) must be used to load newer code in this case. When reloading the application, Gem.refresh will be called so updated code for your application can pick up newly installed RubyGems. It is not recommended that you uninstall libraries your application depends on while Unicorn is running, as respawned workers may enter a spawn loop when they fail to load an uninstalled dependency.

Comment: Sorry, I probably wasn't clear in my first post, the application is a magazine style site and the problem occurs every time I or anyone else posts an article, for some reason the articles are saved okay but the homepage (which displays the latest articles) does not update.

Comment: This sounds like something related to your application and not Nginx / Unicorn.

Answer (score 0):

I should have answered this a lot sooner but got sidetracked, my issue turned out to be that I was I had named scopes that were trying to check against the current date but as I was doing Time.now in the model the current date was always different to that expected passing in the current date/time from the controller into the scope worked perfectly.